# didEnterRegion, didExitRegion not being called

Tags: ios, swift, monitoring, region

I've been experimenting with region monitoring in order to show an alert or a local notification when the user is within the set region. As a first step, I added a print line to see if it works on the debug area. However, while the other lines are being printed, I'm not getting anything for didEnterRegion and didExitRegion.

I am simulating the location to be in/outside of the given region but I am having no luck. It will be great if someone could look at the code below and see what I've missed. Thank you.

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreLocation

    class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var manager = CLLocationManager?()



        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            manager = CLLocationManager()
            let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 48.858400
            let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = 2.294500
            let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
            let radius: CLLocationDistance = CLLocationDistance(100.0)
            let identifier: String = "Notre Dame"

            let currRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)

            manager?.distanceFilter = 10
            manager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            currRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
            currRegion.notifyOnExit = true

            manager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()


            manager?.delegate = self
            manager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true

            manager?.startMonitoringForRegion(currRegion)
            manager?.startUpdatingLocation()    


        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLRegion) {
            print("The monitored regions are: \(manager.monitoredRegions)")
        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
            print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)  {
            NSLog("Entered")
        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
            NSLog("Exited")
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it work by changing

> manager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

to

> manager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

then add to your info.plist file this key
**NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** with value "This is for testing purpose" or whatever text you want this is what will appear to user requesting to use location

Comment: Awesome - that worked like a charm. Thanks for your help! If I may ask though, why is it that requestWhenInUseAuthorization doesn't work? Even when the app was active whilst testing the code?

Comment: I think that you have to requestAlwaysAuthorization() in order to use regions monitoring.
This tutorial provide further information
http://shrikar.com/swift-tutorial-corelocation-and-region-monitoring-in-ios-8/